# How to write Or values in ternary operator Javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to write below code in ternary operator?

```
if(data){
      data;
    }
    else{
     "" || anotherData;
    }
```

I am trying to do :  `data ? data : ""|| anotherData` but it always take second value i.e. `anotherData` when else condition true

Plz suggest.

Comment: an empty string is falsy. what do you want to get in the else part? please add an `if ... else` structure for what you like to test and get.

Comment: condition ? iftrue: iffalse

Comment: Try wrapping them in parentheses: `data ? data : ("" || anotherData)`

Comment: Nina, in some condition I need " "

Comment: please add some use cases.

Comment: I think you want `anotherData || ""`. This way- if anotherData is truthy it will get assigned the value, otherwise empty string. The way you have it the empty string will never get set

Answer (score 0):

It's the other way for the second parameter: `data ? data : (anotherData || '')`

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly clear what you want. What you posted is equivalent to:

```
data || anotherData
```

since `"" || anotherdata` will always evaluate to anotherData.

If you meant `anotherData || ""` then you can simply do:

```
data || anotherData || ""
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `if-else` code itself. Switch the `"" || anotherData` to `anotherData || ""`. According to my understanding of your task, it should get `""` only when both `data` and `anotherData` are `null`.